# Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Unit1:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Grids, StdCtrls, Buttons;

type
  TVector = array of double;
  TMatr = array of TVector;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn2: TBitBtn;
    StringGrid2: TStringGrid;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.Cells[0,0] := 'k1';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1,0] := 'k2';
  StringGrid1.Cells[2,0] := 'k3';
  StringGrid1.Cells[3,0] := 'ñâîáîäíûå ÷ëåíû';

  StringGrid2.Cells[0,0] := 'x1';
  StringGrid2.Cells[0,1] := 'x2';
  StringGrid2.Cells[0,2] := 'x3';

end;


PROCEDURE SIMQ(const Nn:Integer;Var Aa:TMatr;Var Bb:TVector;Var Ks:Integer);
Label M1;
Const Eps=1e-21;
Var Max,U,V : Real; I,J,K1,L : Integer;
Begin
  For I:=1 To Nn Do
    Aa[i,Nn+1]:=Bb[i];
  For I:=1 To Nn Do
    Begin
    Max:=Abs(Aa[i,i]); K1:=I;
    For L:=I+1 To Nn Do
    If (Abs(Aa[l,i])>Max) Then
      Begin
      Max:=Abs(Aa[l,i]);
      K1:=L;
      End;
    If(Max<Eps) Then
      Begin
      Ks:=1;
      Goto M1;
      End
    Else
    Ks:=0;
  If K1<>I Then
    For J:=I To Nn+1 Do
      Begin U:=Aa[i,j];
      Aa[i,j]:=Aa[k1,j];
      Aa[k1,j]:=U;
      End;
  V:=Aa[i,i];
  For J:=I To Nn+1 Do
    Aa[i,j]:=Aa[i,j]/V;
  For L:=i+1 To Nn Do
    Begin
    V:=Aa[l,i];
    For J:=I+1 To Nn+1 Do
    Aa[l,j]:=Aa[l,j]-Aa[i,j]*V;
    End;
  End;
  Bb[nn]:=Aa[Nn,Nn+1];
  For I:=Nn-1 Downto 1 Do
    Begin Bb[i]:=Aa[i,nn+1];
    For J:=I+1 To Nn Do Bb[i]:=Bb[i]-Aa[i,j]*Bb[j];
    End;
  M1:
End;



procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  size = 3 ;
var
  a:TMatr;
  b:TVector;
  erorr,i,j:Integer;
begin
  setlength(a,size,size);
  setlength(b,size);

  for i:=0 to size-1 do
    for j:=0 to size-1 do
    begin
      a[i,j]:= StrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[j+1,i+1]);
    end;
  for i:=0 to size-1 do
    b[i]:=StrToInt(StringGrid2.Cells[1,i+1]);
  SIMQ (size,a,b,error) ;

end;

end.
```

Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка ? 
Вылетает на строчке  SIMQ (size,a,b,error) ; , которая в конце.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы вызываете процедуру SIMQ так:

```
  SIMQ (size,a,b,error) ;
```

у вас опечатка. Вы пытаетесь вместо своей переменной `erorr` передать системную константу `error`. Перепишите так:

```
  SIMQ (size,a,b,erorr) ;
```

И запустится :) Правда, работать правильно не будет - у вас ещё несколько ошибок, связанных с выходом за границы массива, например, здесь:

```
  For I:=1 To Nn Do
    Aa[i,Nn+1]:=Bb[i];
```

У вас массив в диапазоне **0..2**, а вы с ним работаете, как с **1..3**

А здесь:

```
  for i:=0 to size-1 do
    for j:=0 to size-1 do
    begin
      a[i,j]:= StrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[j+1,i+1]);
    end;
  for i:=0 to size-1 do
    b[i]:=StrToInt(StringGrid2.Cells[1,i+1]);
```

вам не хватает предзаполненных ячеек Grid'а, чтобы заполнить матрицу и вектор данными.